# Numbering series of data in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

i have a little problem with SQL SELECT. I want to number continous groups of the same value in column nr 2:

`1,'a'
2,'a,
3,'b'
4,'c'
5,'a'
6,'a'
7,'e'
8,'e'`

The output i want :

`1,'a',1
2,'a,,1
3,'b',2
4,'c',3
5,'a',4
6,'a',4
7,'e',5
8,'e',5`

Is it possible to do it with just a select? I must do it in Vertica's SQL, its not supporting operations on variables in select, so i cant just declare a variable before and increment it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT()`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/TimeSeries/CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENTAnalytic.htm) which is pretty simple. Basically you send in the column that you want to trigger the sequence increment as a parameter, and you order it the way you need it in the window.  It's a Vertica analytic function.

```
SELECT col1, 
       col2,
       CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(col2) OVER ( ORDER BY col1 )
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with window functions.  One method uses `lag()` and then does a cumulative sum of when the value changes:

```
select t.col1, t.col2,
       sum(case when col2 = prev_col2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by col1) as newcol
from (select t.*,
             lag(col2) over (order by col1) as prev_col2
      from t
     ) t
```